# Send a picture from an app to text message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have created an app that lets you take a picture and send it through a text message in windows phone, but the image doesn't show up in the message instead it says the name of the image control. No picture is there.

this is my code:

```
    void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            myImage.Source = bmp;

        }
    }
```

and

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
        smsComposeTask.Body = myImage.Source.ToString();
        smsComposeTask.Show();
    }
```

myImage is the image control that holds the images taken

I think there is some way I have to convert it, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are using sms messages right? SMS is text based, so what is happening is that the ToString method of the image object is being called. It seems that send MMS is not supported in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

you can not sent a pic via sms, because :

> However, it was necessary to limit the length of the messages to 128
>   bytes (later improved to 140 bytes, or 160 seven-bit characters) so
>   that the messages could fit into the existing signaling formats.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service

Answer (score 0):

First, ToString() doesn't mean "convert anything to string" in every case. You are calling ToString() on a Image.Source so the expected behavior is it will say "BitmapImage".

Second, to send images via text you need MMS, but Windows Phone 7 doesn't seem to have a MMS API. So your best choice is an external MMS service (usually paid), and they usually come with their own API.

However, note that MMS requires a data connection, so your best bet may be simply send an email with the image as attachment.

You are a bit ambiguous about "converting" the image here, if your program will run on both the sender and receiver it maybe possible to encode the image as a string, send via SMS and the receiver will decode that string back to an image. But the image data is guaranteed to be very long and unsuitable for SMS, also this approach is overly complicated so I doubt this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Messaging#Picture_message

there are java implementations of http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/nokia/OtaBitmap.html , so if you will reverse engineer it, you can do it in .NET. But the image wil be too small (72x28 px)